# Difference between getBoundingClientRect().top and clientY?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between getBoundingClientRect().top and clientY?

getBoundingClientRect().top gives the position of element relative to viewport.
clientY (from any event at target node) gives position relative to the viewport, not including any scroll offset.

From my quick test the difference in px is not zero.

Comment: `MouseEvent#clientY` is the position of the mouse (ie where the event happened). How is this related to `getBoundingClientRect()`?